# How to decode a numpy array of dtype=numpy.string_?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

I need to decode, with Python 3, a string that was encoded the following way:

```
>>> s = numpy.asarray(numpy.string_("hello\nworld"))
>>> s
array(b'hello\nworld', 
      dtype='|S11')
```

I tried:

```
>>> str(s)
"b'hello\\nworld'"

>>> s.decode()
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7f8dd6e0676b> in <module>()
----> 1 s.decode()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'decode'

>>> s[0].decode()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-fae1dad6938f> in <module>()
----> 1 s[0].decode()

IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the `np.char` collection of string operations.

```
In [255]: np.char.decode(s)
Out[255]: 
array('hello\nworld', 
      dtype='<U11')
```

It accepts the `encoding` keyword if needed.  But `.astype` is probably better if you don't need this.

This `s` is 0d (shape ()), so needs to be indexed with `s[()]`.

```
In [268]: s[()]
Out[268]: b'hello\nworld'
In [269]: s[()].decode()
Out[269]: 'hello\nworld'
```

`s.item()` also works.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you can do this with `astype` which, if `copy = False` will return the array with the contents in the corresponding type:

```
>>> s = numpy.asarray(numpy.string_("hello\nworld"))
>>> r = s.astype(str, copy=False)
>>> r 
array('hello\nworld', 
      dtype='<U11')
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. Now I can recover my string this way: `s = str(s.astype(str))`

Comment: You don't need to convert the type when you can get the regular str directly with `unicode_`.

Comment: I don't control the encoding stage. In my real-world problem, I don't create `s` myself. I just happen to know that it was written to a file after this encoding stage.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, there are two types that represent sequences of characters:    `bytes` and `str` (contain Unicode characters). When you use `string_` as your type, numpy will return `bytes`. If you want the regular `str` you should use `unicode_` type in numpy:

```
>>> s = numpy.asarray(numpy.unicode_("hello\nworld"))
>>> s
array('hello\nworld', 
      dtype='<U11')

>>> str(s)
'hello\nworld'
```

But note that if you don't specify a type for your string (string_ or unicode_) it will return the default str type (which in python 3.x is the str (contain the unicode characters)).

```
>>> s = numpy.asarray("hello\nworld")
>>> str(s)
'hello\nworld'
```

Comment: The reason why I encode with numpy.string_ data is for compatibility. My data goes to a data format called HDF5, and can be potentially read back by other software than just python.

Comment: @PiRK If you want a compatible approach between python versions you should just use `numpy.asarray()` otherwise it has nothing to do with python.

Comment: Unfortunately I also need my output HDF5 files to be compatible with old Fortran libraries, various versions of the Octave software, Matlab... etc