# TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U38') in Python 3.6

Tags: python, dataset, h5py

I'm using h5py to create a dataset, which works perfectly in my laptop. But when I try it in a server, it says *TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U38')*. I've been doing a lot of things but nothing seems to work.

Code:

```
for i in ds.partitions:
    with h5py.File(source_data, "a") as hf:
        hf.create_dataset(f"{i}/dt", data=ds.dataset[i]['dt'], compression="gzip", compression_opts=4)
        hf.create_dataset(f"{i}/gt", data=ds.dataset[i]['gt'], compression="gzip", compression_opts=4)
```

being ds.dataset a dictionary who follows the next structure (This comes from the code in my laptop). The dt is a path (string) and the gt is also a string which includes unicode-egyptian chars.

`{'train': {'dt': ['./data/lines/rm_149_075_029.png', './data/lines/rm_149_075_010.png', (...)'./data/lines/rm_149_075_030.png', './data/lines/rm_149_075_011.png'], 'gt': ['Requisit, n reqri ad hoc, vt ma s vnita fr; go n e ditio, aut notat. Mar vide e', (...)'tis, manet Vnus, seu vnit quoad entit. Proba coa, quia ea raoe, qua extrema ss V-']}`

There's three groups *train*, *validation* and *test*, which have data and the ground truth for each data value.

---

The error in the server goes like this:
Note: It also throws an error for the create_dataset with 'gt'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 90, in <module>
    dataset_creator(raw=raw_path, source_data=sources)
  File "main.py", line 33, in dataset_creator
    hf.create_dataset(f"{i}/dt", dtype=np.dtype('b'), data=ds.dataset[i]['dt'], compression="gzip", compression_opts=4)
  File "/home/dachuser/anaconda3/envs/DevPython3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 116, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
  File "/home/dachuser/anaconda3/envs/DevPython3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 143, in make_new_dset
    dset_id.write(h5s.ALL, h5s.ALL, data)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 211, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.write
  File "h5py/h5t.pyx", line 1633, in h5py.h5t.py_create
  File "h5py/h5t.pyx", line 1694, in h5py.h5t.py_create
TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U38')
```

---

I use Python 3.7.9 and h5py 3.1.0 in my laptop while in the server it's Python 3.6.10 and h5py 2.8.0

Note: I can't do hard changes in the server because it's a shared one.

Comment: Are you trying to read a file that you made on your laptop on a newer version? That might be the cause. I'd recommend downgrading your laptop to what your code will need to run on on the server.

Comment: Looks like h5py 3.0 has big changs in the handling of strings, https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html.  I think earlier versions handled bytestrings ok (e.g.`S10`), but unicode was awkward if not impossible.

Comment: Adding to @hpaulj's comments...based on the `TypeError` about `dtype('<U38')`, it appears you have NumPy Unicode strings. As the docs note: "_h5py will raise an error if you try to store data of this type_" Details here: (https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html#what-about-numpy-s-u-type). The solution is to change the dtype from Unicode to String (from U38 to S38). Then h5py can load the NumPy array into a HDF5 dataset. See this answer for a simple example:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/66494927/10462884)